# NSSortDescriptor most effective way to sort Core Data NSSet objects

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nssortdescriptor

So I have two core data entities - `PersonObj`, and `CheckInObj`. 
Each account has multiple persons. Each person can have multiple checkins, and each checkin has a timestamp.

```
PersonObj {
NSSet * checkIns;
}

CheckInObj {
NSDate *timestamp
}
```

The goal is to sort the all the persons by most recent checkin.

```
NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor =  [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedCheckins = [person.checkIns sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[nameDescriptor]];
CheckInObject *mostRecentCheckin = [sortedMessages lastObject];
```

This gives me the most recent check in.

I can now proceed to sort have a temp cache which has the most recent checkin data which I found vs that corresponding person, and use that to sort each person, and finally have a sorted list of persons.

**Question is:**

Can I somehow run this on a Person's object directly?

```
NSArray *persons = [account.persons allObjects];
```

Instead of

```
 for (Person *person in persons) {
 // find most recent checkin, save temp cache, and resort each time we see a new person in the loop
 }
```

Can I construct an awesome sort descriptor which can do this for me?

I tried.

```
 [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"checkIns.timestamp" ascending:YES];
```

But it wont compare it since its an NSSet.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it that way, because you would need an aggregate. I. e. running `checkIns.timestamp` on persons does not declare, if you want to get the first or last check-in. (Or the average or whatever.) Beside this `-sortDescriptorWithKey` takes a key, not a key path.

However, typically you can solve that with a computed property of `Person` `lastCheckIn`. It depends on your concrete situation, but you can recalculate that property every time the `checkIns` array is changed (with a single comparison) or calculate it on demand, if someone tries to retrieve it.

Comment: Yeah, having an extra property makes it super simple I get it. But I am trying to see if it's possible to do it without one.

Comment: What is your reason not to chose the simple solution? A computed property is not stored.

Comment: I do not know the design philosophy you apply, but a design philosophy that doesn't let you chose a simple (and wide-spreaded) solution for a simple (and wide-spreader) problem, is … Maybe you should recheck the philosophy, not the solution. ;-)

Comment: Lol. Na, I am sure there is a better way. I will keep you posted.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is none. This solution is intended. But keep me on air.

Comment: To the edit of your comment: Now, there is no heavy cost, because all the time, a new check in comes in, you can simply update that extra "flag" with a single comparision. It is a one-liner almost without any costs. However, did you ask yourself, why KVO knows dependent keys?